# uses_allocator says static assertion failed while trying emplace_back a class with allocator_type to a pmr container

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class PmrCustomer which seems implement the uses-allocator construction protocol as the class has a allocator_type and a constructor with trailing-allocator。But I did not provide the copy constructor or move constructor.
then I defined a pmr::vector and I tried to emplace_back a pmr::string to the container, which I think will call the the only constructor I provided.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <iostream>

class PmrCustomer
{
private:
    std::pmr::string name;  
public:
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>;

    PmrCustomer(std::pmr::string n, allocator_type alloc = {}) : name{std::move(n), alloc}, allocator_(alloc) {
    }
    

    //PmrCustomer(const PmrCustomer& c, allocator_type alloc) : name{c.name, alloc} {
    //}
    //PmrCustomer(PmrCustomer&& c, allocator_type alloc) : name{std::move(c.name), alloc} {
    //}

    // setter/getter：
    void setName(std::pmr::string s) {
        name = std::move(s);
    }
    std::pmr::string getName() const {
        return name;
    }
    std::string getNameAsString() const {
        return std::string{name};
    }
    allocator_type allocator_;
};


int main()
{
    std::pmr::vector<PmrCustomer> coll(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
    coll.reserve(100);              
    
    std::pmr::string  c2 {"peter"};
    coll.emplace_back(c2);

    for (const auto& cust : coll) {
        std::cout << cust.getName() << '\n';
    }
}
```

I compiled the codes, but the compiler complains about below errors, seems the emplace_back will use a copy-constructor or move-constructor. I also tried to provided the copy-constructor and move-constructor with a trailing-allocator, and it indeed solve the problem I encountered.but can anyone help to explain how the error is generated if no copy-contructor and move constructor is provided? I think it should not call the copy-constructor or move-constructor. but it doese call!

PS: The compile environment is Ubuntu20.04, using gcc-9, and compile options -std=c++17

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:77,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/memory_resource:37,
                 from d.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/uses_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__uses_alloc<true, PmrCustomer, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>, PmrCustomer>’:
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1294:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_base_of<std::__uses_alloc0, std::__uses_alloc<true, PmrCustomer, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>, PmrCustomer> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2991:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_base_of_v<std::__uses_alloc0, std::__uses_alloc<true, PmrCustomer, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>, PmrCustomer> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/memory_resource:243:18:   required from ‘typename std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::__not_pair<_Up>::type std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp1*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp1 = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Tp = PmrCustomer; typename std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::__not_pair<_Up>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:244:4:   required from ‘static std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> = void]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:350:16:   required from ‘static decltype (std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; decltype (std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = void]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:293:25:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<PmrCustomer*>; _ForwardIterator = PmrCustomer*; _Allocator = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1511:35:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::move_iterator<PmrCustomer*>; _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = PmrCustomer*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:85:14:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
d.cpp:77:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/uses_allocator.h:98:53: error: static assertion failed: construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true
   98 |    is_constructible<_Tp, _Args..., const _Alloc&>>::value,
      |                                                     ^~~~~
In file included from d.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/memory_resource: In instantiation of ‘typename std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::__not_pair<_Up>::type std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp1*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp1 = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Tp = PmrCustomer; typename std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>::__not_pair<_Up>::type = void]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:244:4:   required from ‘static std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> = void]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:350:16:   required from ‘static decltype (std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Args = {PmrCustomer}; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; decltype (std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = void]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:293:25:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<PmrCustomer*>; _ForwardIterator = PmrCustomer*; _Allocator = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1511:35:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::move_iterator<PmrCustomer*>; _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = PmrCustomer*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:85:14:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = PmrCustomer; _Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
d.cpp:77:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/memory_resource:249:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘PmrCustomer::PmrCustomer(PmrCustomer, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<PmrCustomer>&)’
  249 |      ::new(__p) _Tp1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)..., *this);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
d.cpp:50:5: note: candidate: ‘PmrCustomer::PmrCustomer(std::pmr::string, PmrCustomer::allocator_type)’
   50 |     PmrCustomer(std::pmr::string n, allocator_type alloc = {}) : name{std::move(n), alloc}, allocator_(alloc) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
d.cpp:50:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘PmrCustomer’ to ‘std::pmr::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> >’}
   50 |     PmrCustomer(std::pmr::string n, allocator_type alloc = {}) : name{std::move(n), alloc}, allocator_(alloc) {
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
d.cpp:43:7: note: candidate: ‘PmrCustomer::PmrCustomer(const PmrCustomer&)’
   43 | class PmrCustomer
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
d.cpp:43:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
d.cpp:43:7: note: candidate: ‘PmrCustomer::PmrCustomer(PmrCustomer&&)’
d.cpp:43:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: Types stored in a vector [used to require CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Template_parameters). Nowadays it says that it depends on what functions the code uses. Apparently, emplace_back still requires that the objects are relocatable (even if the vector is empty). On my system, the error happen is _Reallocate.

Comment: @BoP: "*Apparently, emplace_back still requires that the objects are relocatable (even if the vector is empty).*" The runtime status of the vector is irrelevant; the function has to be able to relocate the objects even if any particular execution doesn't need to.

Comment: @Nicol - But the reference doesn't say so. We have *"The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container"*. So how are we to know what `emplace_back` requires?

Comment: @BoP: "*So how are we to know what emplace_back requires?*" Have you considered looking at what the standard or [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) *says* that it requires?